# Evaluate the average by grouping rows in Excel/python

Tags: python, excel, csv

I have a `csv` file like the following one (this is just a minimal example; my actual file includes thousands of rows):

```
Main     Submain    Date         Counter
A        A-0        2017-06-09   10
C        C-0        2017-06-09   18
B        B-0        2017-06-09   20
A        A-1        2017-06-09   12
B        B-0        2017-06-30    5
```

What I want to do is when two or more rows have the same main and date, then I want to evaluate the average and (*optionally* create a new csv file) which contains this information like the following one (which corresponds to the previous minimal example).

```
Main    Date         Counter
A       2017-06-09   11
C       2017-06-09   18
B       2017-06-09   20
B       2017-06-30    5
```

I would be more interested in doing that in `Excel` (because I think it is easier to implement), but `python` is ok, as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a pivot table from your data and see the average counter by dates,

[image]

Remove subtotals and repeat the headers to tweak the formatting,

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is there an easy way to save the pivot table as a ***.csv*** file?

Comment: Thank you for the answer (upvoted), but I would be more interested to have exactly the format I mentioned, because I would like to manipulate it.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent I think linking the cells to another sheet and then saving that sheet as csv ?

Comment: @thanasissdr Updated the answer to match the format.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Thanks for the booster !

Answer (score 1):

In case you would also like to try it in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
df2 = df1.groupby(["Main","Date"]).mean()
df2.to_csv("testgrouped.csv")
```

This will give you the same result in the "testgrouped.csv" file:

```
Main,Date,Counter
A,        2017-06-09,11
B,        2017-06-09,20
B,        2017-06-30,5
C,        2017-06-09,18
```